# Transforming image to make it parallel with X axis

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new here, so if there is anything wrong or required in the question. Instead of down voting the question, please, do let me know the problem so I can fix and learn.

I'm working on image transformation. I have some shapes similar to this one

[image: Input]

Expected Output

[image: Final Output]

First, I'm trying to rotate the input shape to this 
[image: Rotation Target]

- Approach 1<sup>st</sup> to find angle using Hough Line Transform, and use that for rotating the image. But due some deformities in input shapes, it does not work. For ex: 
  [image: Hough Line]
  Some input images get even more slanted line.
- Approach 2<sup>nd</sup> By using `cv2.minAreaRect()` which also returns the angle, and using that angle to rotate. Fails in some cases similar to this [image: minArea Fail]

There goes the rotation transformation.
Second, I'm trying using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` and `cv2.warpPerspective()` which requires old co-ordinates and new co-ordinates. 
For that, I tried Harris Corner detection, resulting to this.

[image: cornerHarris]

I guess using the perspective approach will also solve the distorted line on Right side of the object.

Any other ideas on how to approach this problem ?
Thank You.

Comment: Is the bottom side always straight/flat? Is there a known/guessable maximum rotation that is likely to be necessary?

Comment: @MarkSetchell For 97% of shapes, yes the bottom side is always flat, except sometimes there are distortions / non-uniformity on bottom side if the object in the input image has grooves.  
And about known max rotation, right now I'm rotating the image by 90° if the object's height is > than width, and then flipping (horizontal or vertical) depending on whichever is required, to bring the flat base to bottom, and the larger area to the right.

Comment: If you find a way to identify the points that are going to be straight (e.g. the 2 with the biggest y in the last image) you may be able to calculate the slope of this line and rotate it. So the hard part is to actually get always these 2 points correctly every time. Maybe getting the buttom contour and doing some kind of line fitting to this points with some RANSAC approach perhaps may work

Comment: @api55 Ok, the hardest part you mentioned (getting the Ys) is where I am stuck at, I'm still thinking for different approaches to get the Ys. I'll update as soon as I find a proper way to achieve that.

Comment: the bottom line of the object looks curved to me, is it really straight in the image? If you want to rotate, I would not use warping from region to region, but instead use a rotation matrix around some center point. This center point must be a point on the straight line of the object.

Comment: @Micka No, the bottom part is not exactly a straight line.  That's why HoughLine fails.

Comment: but you want a straight line in the end (as in your expected result)? Or do you just want to rotate?

Comment: @Micka, Initial target is to rotate the image. The image in expected output, is the expected final outcome, I haven't been able to wrap my mind around it on how will i do that, yet.

Comment: the problem is to detect the bottom side and to find the rotation angle, right? If only 97% of the bottom sides are flat, how would you define the bottom side? From your image I would try to measure the "straightness" of contour arc segments and choose the longest "nearly straight" segment to be to bottom side.

Comment: @Micka, I've already done bottom side detection by vertically dividing the image into two parts, and flipping it if the left part has more area than the right part. Repeated same for horizontal flip, if top part has more area than bottom one, then image is flipped horizontally.

Comment: then try to fit a line to the whole bottom side or with ransac. Or try convex hull.

Comment: @Micka Thanks, I solved it. I divided the shape in number of blocks and take the extreme bottom point of each block, and then use that points for fitLine. And use the line points from fitLine, to find the angle with X-Axis, and rotate the image accordingly.

Comment: @api55 Thanks for the suggestion.